# Issue with setting upper limit to y-xis on graph with matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib, yaxis

The following code returns the nice graph provided here:

[image: provided here].

However, when I add a line code such as `ax.set_ylim(ymax=14)` I get the following graph:

[image: following graph].

Clearly there is something wrong. Could anyone help me figure out what?

Thanks!

```
fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(15, 10))

# Set bins for histograms:
bins = np.arange(0, 40+0.5, 1)

# set interval on this bins for curve fitting:
xplot = np.linspace(min(bins), max(bins), 100)

# -- make a histogram 
ax.grid(axis='y', zorder=0)
plt.axvline(x=af_farm_w_speedb.mean(), color='black', linestyle='dashed', linewidth=2, label = "Mean speed at control")
plt.axvline(x=af_farm_w_speedw.mean(), color='red', linestyle='dashed', linewidth=2, label = "Mean speed at treatment")
ax.hist([af_farm_w_speedb, af_farm_w_speedw], bins=bins, density=True, alpha = 1, align='left', zorder=1, rwidth=0.8, color=['lightsteelblue','grey'], label = ['Records at control', 'Records at treatment'])
ax.tick_params(axis='both', which='major', labelsize=30)
ax.set_yticklabels([0, 2, 4, 6, 8, 10, 12])
ax.set_title('Post-farm wind speed distribution', fontsize=35)
(scale, a, shape, c) = stats.exponweib.fit(af_farm_w_speedw, f0=1, floc=0)
ax.plot(xplot, stats.exponweib.pdf(xplot, *stats.exponweib.fit(af_farm_w_speedb, 1, 1, scale=1, loc=0)), zorder=3, color = "black", linewidth=1.6, label="Weibull fit at control")
ax.plot(xplot, stats.exponweib.pdf(xplot, *stats.exponweib.fit(af_farm_w_speedw, 1, 1, scale=1, loc=0)), zorder=3, color = "red", linewidth=1.6, label="Weibull fit at treatment")
fig.text(0.6, 0.55, "Mean speed at treatment: {:.4g}".format(af_farm_w_speedw.mean()), fontsize=18)
fig.text(0.6, 0.6, "Mean speed at control: {:.4g}".format(af_farm_w_speedb.mean()), fontsize=18)
ax.legend(prop=dict(size=18))
```

Comment: Can you add something like `af_farm_w_speedb = np.random.normal(15, 4, 1000)` and 
`af_farm_w_speedw = np.random.normal(17, 4, 1000)` to get an independent example?

Comment: The problem is that you call `ax.set_yticklabels(...)` without regard to the existing ticks. Apparently, the y-axis goes from 0.0 to about 0.12. To limit it, you need `ax.set_ylim(ymax=0.14)`. But you also should set `ax.set_yticks(...)`, e.g. `np.arange(0, 0.14, 0.2)`

Comment: Hello! Thank you JohanC! You solved my problem!

Comment: Your plot was still there, only reduced in height with a factor of 100. Matplotlib's interactive window lets you zoom in.